# Eclipse p2 mirror keeping sources

Tags: eclipse-rcp, p2

I am looking for a way to do a mirror of a p2 repository - reduce it to the needed content and still keep the sources attached. So far I have been trying to use the ant task to mirror the repository:

```
<target name="R2020-09-partial" description="Reduced 2020-09 update site only containing feratures and plugins directly or indirectly references by the update site">
    <p2.mirror>
        <repository location="${destinationFolder}${ant.project.invoked-targets}" />
        <source>
            <repository location="${destinationFolder}/R2020-09" />
        </source>
        <slicingOptions followStrict="false" />
        <iu id="org.eclipse.platform.feature.group" />
        <iu id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" />
        [...]
        <iu id="org.eclipse.help.feature.group" />
    </p2.mirror>
</target>
```

this is working fine and a mirror is created, but there are only very few of the original sources still part of the mirror. Somehow it is not *none* or *all* but only *some*.

How do I make it that the p2.mirror will copy *all* sources of the jars it takes?

I have been reading this
https://rtist.hcldoc.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_repositorytasks.htm but I have not been able to find the clue I was looking for.

Thank you all
Nico

PS. for clarification the destinationFolder contains a R2020-09 mirror without any slicing. This is where I see the sources as well. They seem to get lost in the slicing step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the three mentioned feature install units, there are corresponding source install units:

```
<iu id="org.eclipse.platform.feature.group" />
<iu id="org.eclipse.platform.source.feature.group" />

<iu id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" />
<iu id="org.eclipse.rcp.source.feature.group" />

[...]

<iu id="org.eclipse.help.feature.group" />
<iu id="org.eclipse.help.source.feature.group" />
```

Instead of Ant, you might consider to use Maven with Tycho's [tycho-p2-extras:mirror](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-extras/tycho-p2-extras-plugin/mirror-mojo.html) (see [here for an example](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/28854a9ebddf563e5154c95392c9d1de4c2ef385/mirror-non-p2/pom.xml#L25-L51)).

Comment: Thanks - this helped a lot. I was not aware that there are source code features. Now the trick is to find the correct features :)